# Is it possible to insert into temporary table in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, temporary

I tested below queries using Databricks with Apache Spark 2.4:

```sql
%sql

<step1>
create temporary view temp_view_t
as select 1 as no, 'aaa' as str;

<step2>
insert into temp_view_t values (2,'bbb');
```

And then I got this error message.

> Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: Inserting into an RDD-based table is not allowed.;;
>   'InsertIntoTable Project [1 AS no#824, aaa AS str#825], false, false
>   +- LocalRelation [col1#831, col2#832]

**My questions are**

1. Is it impossible to insert into temporary table in spark?
2. How can I work for creating temporary data in spark sql?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We `can't` insert data into the temporary table but we can mimic the insert with **`union all`** (or) **`union`**(to remove duplicates).

**`Example:`**

```
#create temp view
spark.sql("""create or replace temporary view temp_view_t as select 1 as no, 'aaa' as str""")

spark.sql("select * from temp_view_t").show()
#+---+---+
#| no|str|
#+---+---+
#|  1|aaa|
#+---+---+

#union all with the new data
spark.sql("""create or replace temporary view temp_view_t as select * from temp_view_t union all select 2 as no, 'bbb' as str""")

spark.sql("select * from temp_view_t").show()                                                                     
#+---+---+
#| no|str|
#+---+---+
#|  1|aaa|
#|  2|bbb|
#+---+---+

#to eliminate duplicates we can use union also. 
spark.sql("""create or replace temporary view temp_view_t as select * from temp_view_t union select 1 as no, 'aaa' as str""")

spark.sql("select * from temp_view_t").show()
#+---+---+
#| no|str|
#+---+---+
#|  1|aaa|
#|  2|bbb|
#+---+---+
```

Comment: If you get ```AnalysisException: Recursive view```  this may be a change in spark 3.2+ https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-37690

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the answer advising to do `UNION` works (on recent Databricks runtime at least, 8.2 spark runtime 3.1.1), a recursive view is detected at the execution. Example of the code above gives :

```
AnalysisException: Recursive view `temp_view_t` detected (cycle: `temp_view_t` -> `temp_view_t`)
```

Which seems pretty logic.
Why not use some intermediary temp view or to write the view as a managed Delta table, this way it will handle `INSERT` operations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can insert into temp view but it must be based on df build from file. Then new row will be saved as separte file on storage.

For instance

```
df.read.parquet(path).createOrReplaceTempView('temp')

spark.sql("INSERT INTO temp VALUES (....)")
```

Comment: Please give proper explanation and  comments in your answer so that it is relevant to the OP of question.

Answer (score 0):

You can create temporary dataset by creating empty dataframe and perform union on it to add new rows.
This approach is avoiding the recursive view method.

```
# create empty dataframe
temp_df = spark.createDataFrame(data = [], schema = 'no int, str string')
# add rows using union
temp_df = temp_df.union(spark.sql('select 1 as no, \'aaa\' as str'))
temp_df = temp_df.union(spark.sql('select 2 as no, \'bbb\' as str'))
# print dataframe
temp_df.show()
+---+---+
| no|str|
+---+---+
|  1|aaa|
|  2|bbb|
+---+---+
```

Hope it resolves your issue.