# Create temp table in Azure Databricks and insert lots of rows

Tags: sql, databricks, sql-insert, azure-databricks

Here's the end result of what I'm trying to do, because I think that I'm making it needlessly complicated.

I want to query data where UPC_ID IN (VERY LONG LIST OF UPCS). Like, 20k lines.

I thought that perhaps the easiest way to do this would be to create a temporary table, and insert the lines 1000 at a time (and then use that table for the WHERE condition.)
When I try to run

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP_ITEM (UPC_ID BIGINT NOT NULL)
```

I get

```
[PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near '#'line 1, pos 13
```

The list of UPCs comes from a spreadsheet, and there's no shared attributes where I can just SELECT INTO or generate the list using anything that already exists in the database.

I know that I'm missing something painfully stupid here, but I am stuck. Help?

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there...
I hope this is in Databricks....

Basically we cannot insert directly, but you can simulate it with the output of an insert statement...

```sql
create
or replace temporary view TEMP_ITEM as
select
  1 as UPC_ID
UNION
select
  2 as UPC_ID
...
...
```

Please refer to the below link for further details...

[Is it possible to insert into temporary table in spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60923021/is-it-possible-to-insert-into-temporary-table-in-spark)

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

If your spreadsheet is an xlsx file and you can get a copy of your spreadsheet into a location that is readable from databricks, you can use `pyspark.pandas` to copy it, cast it into a spark DF, then set that as a temp view. From there you should be able to use SQL to run the filter.

Here's an example using an ADLS container with Azure Databricks...

```
%py
import pyspark.pandas as pd

adlsConnStr = (
  'abfss://{container}@{account}.dfs.core.windows.net/'
  .format(container='adlsCntnr', account='adlsAccnt')
)
adlsPath = 'path/to/file.xlsx'
pd.read_excel(
  f'{adlsConnStr}{adlsPath}', '$Sheet1'
).to_spark().createOrReplaceTempView('viewName')
```

Then in your next cell...

```
%sql
select *
from source.table

join viewName
  using (UPC_ID)  -- or another join condition
```

If your spreadsheet happens to be a CSV or other spark-readable file, this gets easier...

```
%sql
create or replace temp view viewName using CSV
options (
  path 'abfss://adlsCntnr@adlsAccnt.dfs.core.windows.net/path/to/file.csv'
  header 'true' -- if your first row has the column names
  -- may need to tell it to infer types or cast columns to get a proper schema later
);

select *
from source.table

join viewName
  using (UPC_ID) -- or other join condition
```